# When to use ENUM and when ENTITIES to handle domain states?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, solid-principles

I need to handle different states of certain entities (domain) in my application. So, during the execution of a process (a service) they might be updated from one status to another, i.e:

`open -> pending`
`pending -> error`
`pending -> success`

My first approach is to create an ENUM class. However, this solution breaks OPEN/CLOSE Principle, as new states might come in the future and I will need to adapt the ENUM class.

Another way it is to create a `table` with different states, but I am not sure how implement this solution in a proper way.

When is one solution better than the other? Is there a better way than those I've brought here?

Answer (score 0):

Using an enum like EntityStatusEnum which defines the fixed list of valid states for each entity is a perfect use for an enum.

If you have many different Entity types, you can adhere to the open/closed principal by using common interfaces so you can change or vary their implementation without impacting the code that uses them.

If your different Entities have different combinations of valid statuses it would be easier to implement this with specific enums for each type, and avoid the (artificial?) restriction of trying to share a common enum between different entities. e.g. define an EntityAStatusEnum for use by EntityA and an EntityBStatusEnum for EntityB.

Comment: My problem is not that. I just have one (for the moment :D) Entity which have this status.
My question here is how to define a good architecture for that? If create a Fix enum class for the states and a new status should be added, I need to modify this enum class -> open / close principle is violated.

Comment: @lordneru do these status codes change so frequently that you're going to be making updates to this code every week, every day? If so then this sounds like configuration metadata that needs to be externalized from your code to another configurable source, like a property file or a database table. However, carefully consider what problem you're trying to solve. If you don't have a problem where the status codes need to change on a regular basis, don't attempt to design a solution for that problem. Don't solve a problem you don't have.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It definitely is the right one! I am going to implement the states as ENUM. Thanks!